# Working with constraints in storyboard and code

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a button and a view, when the button is not appearing I want the view to be extended (using top constraint) to fill up the white space, the button appears I want the view to shrink to make room for the button. The problem is I am getting this error:

> failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "NSLayoutConstraint for (null): Constraint must contain a first layout item"

I set constraints in storyboard, and declare the top constraint by this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *containerTopConstraint;
```

This is how I change the value of the constraints:

```
[_containerTopConstraint setConstant:20];
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try putting your views inside of a `UIStackView`. It automatically repositions views when the `isHidden` property changes on one of them to take up the empty space.

Comment: It's a little too complicated for a stack view

Comment: Then you'll need to add more information to your question about why it's too complicated. The question is very light on details about the view you're trying to build.